# Not work ReportViewer and ASP.NET MVC 3 in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reportviewer

I have an application that combines webforms with mvc3 hosted in IIS.

What corresponds to MVC 3 works perfectly in IIS, but when I try to access the pages **.aspx** not work

Error:

**Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.**

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

I have configured the Application Pools with .NET 4. The error occurs only when I try to access the pages .aspx. The rest works perfectly.

Note: When running the alplicacion with VS 2010 all works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

### Fix for Issue with 'targetFramework'

You need to register IIS with Asp.net v 4.0. 
Using command prompt do it `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -i`
<strike>Your `application pool` under which the application hosted may not be `Asp.net v 4.0`.</strike> Create a new application pool of Asp.net version `v 4.0` and `managed pipeline mode` - `Integrated`. And host your application under that.

### Fix for Issue with Report Viewer

For fixing the issue with report viewer , you should install [Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442) in the server.( ASp.Net MVC 3 also need to be installed in the server)